# What is meant by "$?" in shell?

Tags: linux, shell

I am using Debian 6.0. I know the regular command line arguments but couldn't find what `$?` is meant for?  Does anyone have an idea of what is meant by `$?` in Linux shell?

Answer (score 15):

*bash*, not *shell*. (Bash is but one of several possible shells. It is the most common though)

It means the exit code of the last command that executed.

See here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/othertypesv.html and here http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html

Comment: Every UNIX shell I have access to uses `$?` to indicate the last program's return code. This includes not just `bash` but also standard Bourne shell, `ksh`, `csh`, and `zsh`. Pretty much every UNIX shell in existence agrees on this one.

Comment: The shell he's using in Linux is almost certainly `bash`, but `$?` oringinates from the Bourne shell.

Comment: @clee You're right. Guess it was a knee-jerk reaction I have to people not aware that there is a difference between shell and bash.

Comment: Well, Bash is a shell as well.

Answer (score 5):

For shells supporting this shell variable "$?" contains the return code of a command executed most recently.

So if you're running program "abc" which returns 1 on exit doing

```
$ echo $?
```

gives "1" - the return code.

And it is not only available in bash, also other shells have this feature.

Answer (score 2):

The return code of the last executed program.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, they have mentioned that it is the return code of the last executed program, but no one mentioned that if it's more than 0 it's probably indicating an error. It is general practice that when a program or script executes without error it returns a value of 0 to indicate that it has finished with no errors. Not all programs and scripts do, but they should.

Checking the value of $? after running a linux command should tell you if there were errors or not. Check the docs of each program to know what the possible return values are. Some won't return a value but most do. In your scripts you should end with 'return X' where X is some value 0=good/no errors and anything greater than zero indicates some problem occurred. Even if all you use are values of 0 or 1 it's good practice. This allows other scripts to know whether the next line/command should be executed based on the success or failure of the last command. It makes for smarter scripting and better control.